# How to get a "1.2" formatted string from String?

Tags: java, string, substring

I am working with Java strings.  My problem is that I have a string of "1.500000154". How can I get a resultant string "1.5" from the original "1.500000154" string?

1.500000154 >>>>>>>> 1.5

Answer (score 5):

```
BigDecimal bigDecimal = new BigDecimal("1.500000154");
bigDecimal.setScale(1, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP)
String result  - bigDecimal.toString();
```

Answer (score 3):

This also worked for me:

```
String str = "1.5000000154";
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("##.#");
System.out.println(df.format(Double.parseDouble(str)));
```

Prints:

> 1.5

More information on the Decimal Format can be obtained [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html). This also takes care of round up should there be the need. For instance, `1.5900000154`, would result into `1.6`.